# What is the best way to backup PostgresSQL individual Database (Not Instance) in google CloudSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have PostgresSQL Instance in google cloud SQL with multiple databases, Wanted to back up individual database into google cloud storage. What would be be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: While you totally CAN do this, I'm wondering what the use case for doing it is? Cloud SQL already backs you up, and can do it on-demand, or automatically once you set it up: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups (If you didn't know about this, I'm happy to also post this as an answer, but wanted to find out the use-case before I set it as an answer).

Comment: Each db backup task needs to be performed in different time period,
If i am not wrong, cloud sql back is for instance not for database

Comment: Gotcha, glad to see you came up with a solution with the functions, that's a good way to do it IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a dump file from your instance with your database to a Cloud Storage bucket:

[Exporting data using Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting#export-database)

1. Create a bucket:

   ```
     gsutil mb -p [PROJECT_NAME] -l [LOCATION_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
   ```
2. Describe the instance you are exporting from:

   ```
     gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]
   ```
3. Copy the serviceAccountEmailAddress field
4. Add the service account to the bucket ACL as a writer:

   ```
     gsutil acl ch -u [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS]:W gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
   ```
5. Export the database:

   ```
     gcloud sql export sql [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/sqldumpfile.gz \
                         --database=[DATABASE_NAME]
   ```
6. If you do not need to retain the permissions provided by the ACL you set previously, remove the ACL:

   ```
     gsutil acl ch -d [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I have ended up creating a cloud function that can export sql data in to cloud storage. This function can be triggered by cloud Pub/Sub using cloud scheduler